# Having trouble with methods in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to add and remove balls into an array, I'm only allowed to use an array (not an arraylist).
I'm having trouble with the add and remove ball methods and keep getting an " insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" " error on length for add and remove ball methods. Not sure how to fix the problem.
Help appreciated.

```
private final int DIAMETER = 60;
private java.awt.Color _currentColor;
//private SmartEllipse _ball;

SmartEllipse [] myBalls = new SmartEllipse [25];


public BallPanel () {

    super();
    this.setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);

    myBalls = new SmartEllipse[0];

    _currentColor = java.awt.Color.red;

    this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());


}

//translate the click coordinates to a grid coordinate
     public java.awt.Point translatePoint(java.awt.Point aPoint)
     {

         int x = aPoint.x;
         int y = aPoint.y;

         aPoint.x = x / 20;
         aPoint.y = y / 20;

         return aPoint;

     }


    //find a ball in the array
     public int findBall(java.awt.Point p)
     {
         for (SmartEllipse se : myBalls )
         {       
             java.awt.Point translatedPoint = translatePoint(se.getLocation());

             if (translatedPoint.x == p.x && translatedPoint.y == p.y)
                 return myBalls.length;
         }

         return -1;

     }

     // remove a ball from the array
     public void removeBall(SmartEllipse p)
     { 
         myBalls.length-1;
         this.repaint();
         this.revalidate();
     }

     //add a peg to the array
     public void addBall(SmartEllipse p)
     {
         myBalls.length;
         this.repaint();
         this.revalidate();
     }


 public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics aBrush)
 {
        super.paintComponent(aBrush);
        java.awt.Graphics2D betterBrush = (java.awt.Graphics2D) aBrush;

        for (SmartEllipse se : myBalls )
        {
            se.draw(betterBrush);
            se.fill(betterBrush);
        }
 }



 private class MyMouseListener extends javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter
 {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
     {
         // get X and Y of click
         // translate X and Y to grid
         // check peg array for duplicate
         // if duplicate, remove ball
         // else add ball to ball array

         java.awt.Point p = translatePoint(e.getPoint());

         // Adjust the coordinates


         int index = findBall(p);

         for (int i = 0; i< myBalls.length; i++)
         {


            myBalls[i] = null;


         if ( index != -1)
             remove(myBalls.length);
         else
             addBall(new SmartEllipse(_currentColor, p.x, p.y));

         }

     }
 }
```

}

Comment: I would love to help you, but I need some clarification.  When you add a ball, does it go in a specific slot in the array, or just at the end of the array?  Same thing for removing?  Does every ball have an assigned slot, or are you just randomly adding and removing them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question since you don't specify very well where you're getting the error, but it looks as if you are declaring myBalls as an array of 25 elements, but then in the constructor your are assigning it a new array of zero elements. You can't add anything to an array of zero elements.

Comment: Ok. I'm getting the error at myBall.length for both the removeBall and  addBall methods. Also I would like my app to start off with a screen that doesn't contain any balls, however I would like the array to hold up to 25 balls.

Comment: remove this line "myBalls = new SmartEllipse[0];" Your array is already declared as to contain up to 25 balls, and because you have not added any, it's empty.